# Сессии и проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8, сессия

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос. У меня всё в кодировке UTF-8 и, когда создаю сессию, то выдаёт такую ошибку.

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   Y:\home\rating.ru\www\index.php:1) in Y:\home\rating.ru\www\index.php
>   on line 2

Когда меняю кодировку в windows-1251 или windows-1250, то этих ошибок нет, но текст на странице становится таким "�������". Что мне делать?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема ...

> Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent

... решается с помощью директивы `output_buffering = On` (по умолчанию - Off), см. php.ini

А вообще, как уже было сказано, стартовать сессию нужно до того, как что-либо будет выведено в окно браузера.

Answer (score 0):

Сессию надо начинать до любого вывода (пробелы тоже считаются).

Если пишете в редакторе, проверьте, чтобы не стояло галки "выравнивать байты в кодировке UTF8" или как-то так. В hex-режиме в этом случае первый байт стоит FF.

Comment: Вот она начинается у меня сверху! Или это не так?


    <?php
    session_start();
    include("blocks/bd.php");
    $tipe = mysql_query("SELECT title,meta_d,meta_k,text,bitva FROM settings WHERE page='index'",$db);
    $my1 = mysql_fetch_array($tipe);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
    </head>

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, у вас случаем скрипты не в кодировке utf8 + bom? :D
Кстати была страшная история у меня когдато... Это может происходить так-же если до выполнения session_start выводится сообщение об ошибке(что впринцыпе логично но когдато убило у меня полдня :))

Comment: все нормально разобрался спасиба!

Comment: незачто, если не вкурсе че это такое советую погуглить и читнуть для саморазвития :)